# Rails 3 user to Rails 2: Installing gems without a gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm familiar with Rails 3, but not rails 2. I've just inherited a rails 2 project with no Gemfile, but a bunch of `config.gem` lines in `config/environment.rb`

I'm just wondering how I to install these. `bundle install` returns `Could not locate Gemfile`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install gems in rails 2.x by using the rake command

```
   rake gems:install
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bundle install` if you use this guide:

http://gembundler.com/rails23.html

To have "backwards" compatibility for bundler.